# FK linking question

Tags: database, schema

I have postal codes which is mapped to
city_id
country_id.

I have city which is mapped to
country_id.

So in essence I can reach country from postal either directly through a FK or by jumping via the city table. Any reason I should not go with what I have done and only have 1 link from postal to country, that is via city?

Answer (score 0):

It's alright. It's design thing. Purist may complain redundancy, but there is no big deal, IMO.

Comment: Reason i use it i 1 less join at the cost of 1 extra colunm.